# Update records with date field value less than max date minus a number of days for its group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update records in a table whose date field has a value that is less than the max date value minus a number of days for all records in the table that share the same value of another field.

So from the list below; set the Header_Ready field = 1 if the record's Header_BusDate is less than the maximum date value (minus a number of days) for all the records in the table with the same Header_SiteKey field value.

I need to do it without using a cursor (I have that already but my employer is allergic to cursors).

```
CREATE TABLE #Headers
(
    Header_Key      decimal(15,0)   NOT NULL,
    Header_SiteKey  decimal(15,0)   NOT NULL,
    Header_BusDate  smalldatetime   NOT NULL,
    Header_Ready    bit             NOT NULL default(0)
)

INSERT INTO #Headers
VALUES
(610, 4, '2023-04-16', 0),
(609, 4, '2023-04-15', 0),
(608, 4, '2023-04-14', 0),
(607, 4, '2023-04-13', 0),
(606, 4, '2023-04-12', 0),
(605, 4, '2023-04-11', 0),
(604, 4, '2023-04-10', 0),
(617, 6, '2032-12-31', 0),
(616, 6, '2023-04-15', 0),
(615, 6, '2023-04-14', 0),
(614, 6, '2023-04-13', 0),
(613, 6, '2023-04-12', 0),
(612, 6, '2023-04-11', 0),
(611, 6, '2023-04-10', 0)

/* This doesn't work */
UPDATE #Headers
   SET Header_Ready = 1
 WHERE Header_BusDate < 
       (SELECT MAX(Header_BusDate) - 2 day
          FROM #Headers hdrs 
         WHERE hdrs.Header_SiteKey = Header_SiteKey)

SELECT * FROM #Headers

DROP TABLE #Headers
```

Here are the results I would like (output from my cursor solution):

```
Header_Key  Header_SiteKey  Header_BusDate      Header_Ready
610         4               2023-04-16 00:00:00            0
609         4               2023-04-15 00:00:00            0
608         4               2023-04-14 00:00:00            0
607         4               2023-04-13 00:00:00            1
606         4               2023-04-12 00:00:00            1
605         4               2023-04-11 00:00:00            1
604         4               2023-04-10 00:00:00            1
617         6               2032-12-31 00:00:00            0
616         6               2023-04-15 00:00:00            1
615         6               2023-04-14 00:00:00            1
614         6               2023-04-13 00:00:00            1
613         6               2023-04-12 00:00:00            1
612         6               2023-04-11 00:00:00            1
611         6               2023-04-10 00:00:00            1
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What indication do you have that your code doesn't work? Do you have an error? Seems like `WHERE hdrs.Header_SiteKey = Header_SiteKey` should be `WHERE hdrs.Header_SiteKey = #Headers.Header_SiteKey` and `MAX(Header_BusDate) - 2 day` should be `DATEADD(day, -2, Max(Header_BusDate))`

Comment: When I run the query, every record with a date less than 2032-12-31 has its Header_Ready set to 1. It is using the max date regardless of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `WHERE hdrs.Header_SiteKey = Header_SiteKey` to `WHERE hdrs.Header_SiteKey = #Headers.Header_SiteKey`

SQL Server is assuming you mean the Header_SiteKey in the Hdrs table, which means you are updating every row:

```
UPDATE #Headers
SET Header_Ready = 1
WHERE Header_BusDate < 
   (SELECT MAX(Header_BusDate) - 2 day
     FROM #Headers hdrs 
     WHERE hdrs.Header_SiteKey = #Headers.Header_SiteKey)
```